# Is there a Latex template that is closely similar to Satoshi Nakamoto's Bitcoin Paper?

Tags: overleaf, templates

I am looking for a template that closely resembles the famous original bitcoin paper called "Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System." Is there a way to recreate it or access a template?[image]

Comment: Have you given something a try?  That looks like every LaTeX paper I've ever created.

Comment: The standard `article` class looks very much like the article, but isn't not exactly equal. The original article isn't written in LaTeX, but in Open/LibreOffice Writer. Some differences: The title in the original article is bold with a smaller font. The Abstract title is the first word of the paragraph rather than centered on top of the abstract. The section headers are a bit smaller and have a dot after the number. If that doesn't bother you just use `article`. Otherwise tweak it a bit, for example using `titlesec`.